# Is it possible to map the magento database to a hibernate class in java?

Tags: java, magento

I need to map or query the magento orders tables from outside magento, using a java application. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Is it a database?  Can you connect to it like any database?  What happens when you try?

Comment: I know it is not a database.

Comment: Then what is it?  The Magento documentation seems to make multiple references to a database.  Are you saying their documentation is incorrect?  It's not really clear what you're asking at this point.  What specifically are you trying to accomplish, and in what way is the product's API not meeting that need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is is possible to do?

**Yes, it is.**

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento), Magento uses MySQL/MariaDB database and both database types, as far as I know, are supported by Hibernate/JDBC so yes, it is possible.

I should recommend you to start reading the [Hibernate documentation](http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/5.1/) to get to know how to do it.